# Best way to deploy a VS-2008 web project

Tags: asp.net

what is the preferred method of deploying a web project? Just copy the dll's after compiling in release mode and registering them? or using NSIS to build an installer or the MS set up project.

Answer (score 5):

I usually use a [Web Deployment Project](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en) per WebSite or WebApplication, it allows me to manage build configurations, merging, and define pre-post build MSBuild tasks.

You can also take a look to the [Microsoft Web Application Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/channel/products/WebApplicationInstaller.aspx), it will be really nice, but it still in beta stage, however you can try it...

Answer (score 1):

This depends greatly on where your webapp is going and the experience you wish to provide.
If you deploy to a web host its best to use xcopy deploy and documentation.  If you have a  real end system its simpler to create an installer to do all the leg work for your customers and maybe save your self some documentation work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend investing in setting up a continuous integration process (CruiseControl.Net or  TeamCity etc...) As you are probably not only going to deploy it to your customer only once.

Having an automatic deploy at the push of a button is a Godsend. If you invest a few days you can have automatic deploy to a dev-environment every time someone checks in code (and it compiles and all tests pass), set up daily deploys to a test environment and have a button to automatically deploy it to a staging environment whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Andreas, I am in the process of getting CC.Net. In the meanwhile, I am using the Web Deployment Project. Using this and going through the set up, it creates a 'release' folder with a bin folder conntaining dll's and also the aspx in the parent folder.

I assume I can now create an MSI file using the 'release' folder or do i need to do something different to create an MSI which i can run on the client server