# How to publish aspnet.mvc site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, deployment

I have to publish my asp.net mvc site to the customer server. Which files should I publish to avoid to distribute the project source code?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a right-click on your project an build a deployment package? VS will pack all files you need. And for the Client server use msdeploy to publish

And next time use the search cause you will find lots of posts about this:

[Best way to deploy a VS-2008 web project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369839/best-way-to-deploy-a-vs-2008-web-project)

[How to deploy my asp.net project in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980150/how-to-deploy-my-asp-net-project-in-iis)

[Is it possible to deploy asp.net mvc project on IIS server without installing of mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872229/is-it-possible-to-deploy-asp-net-mvc-project-on-iis-server-without-installing-of)